# How to change the order that gems are loaded from within one of the gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two gems "CoreGem" and "AddonGem". Addon Gem adds extra functionality which will overwrite the core gem.

How do i make sure that if the second gem is added it will overwrite the views and assets of the first.

So far it works when adding to the main app:

```
 config.railties_order = [ :main_app, AddonGem::Engine, :all]
```

But i'd want to do this from within the AddonGem.

Thanks

Comment: I never heard of a way to re-order loading of files. But who knows...

Comment: just thought of something, anyone know if making CoreGem a dependency of AddonGem will change the order?

Answer (score 2):

## Where `railties_order` is used

`railties_order` is used here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L317

to determine the ordering of `initializer` blocks to run,

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L337

found in other gems.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L47

So setting `railties_order` inside an `initializer` block would be rather pointless, as by the time the `initializer` block was called, `railties_order` was already set and is in used by the rest of the application.

## What you could do instead

Apparently a bunch more `initializer` blocks are inside the `Rails::Application::Bootstrap`.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb

Those are prepended before the main application's initializer blocks:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application.rb#L262

So perhaps you can monkey-patch the Bootstrap module with some initializers? I guess that's your call.

Answer (score -1):

Make a generator in `AddonGem` that injects this code

```
config.railties_order = [ :main_app, AddonGem::Engine, :all]
```

in the main app, like a `addongem:install` command.

Just for completion, although it's an easy way out. It should be possible to hook the addon after core somewhere.

Comment: this is not a good alternative as it might break that app or other gems (which have the same problem). I'd really like to only change the order of my gems